# How to obfuscate swift code for cocoa pods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I have created a pod library. But my code in the library is completely visible when imported. How can I hide the content of code and just show signatures?

It should be something like this.

```
import Foundation
import WebKit
import UIKit
import SafariServices

internal enum SdkErrorCode : String {

    case INITIALIZATION_PENDING

    case OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS
}

public class XYZ : NSObject, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    public func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController)

    public func setUserCloseCallback(cb: (() -> ())?)

    public func setResponse(url: URL)

    public func activateUser(data: [String : Any], cb: @escaping (([String : Any]) -> Void?)) -> [String : Any]?

    public func loginUser(cb: @escaping (([String : Any]) -> Void?)) -> [String : Any]?


}
```

Comment: If you want to hide the implementation of your library/SDK, you should consider building it as a framework, only the resources, nibs and headers should be visible then. I believe pods are for open source projects. You can use provide Pods but this probably isn't what you are looking for

Comment: Yes I want to hide my implementations and hard coded strings. But I want my user to see what are the function signature available to them

Comment: You can do this using a framework or static library

Comment: How can I build it as framework?

Comment: I am creating it as cocoa touch framework. but I don't have much idea how to configure it. Can you guide me?

Comment: I don't have time and this isn't the best place to provide a full on tutorial. Check this article out: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, CocoaPods are intended for open source projects, and include all your source code. You want to build a framework or static library.

Do a Google search on "Xcode Create Framework". The top hit I found was this [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios) article. Those are generally very good, although I don't know how current that one is. There are quite a few hits in the Google search results however.

Comment: I have already created the library and is published. But it contains some private asset in it. So I just want a way so that code implementation is not visible. More properly I would say it is SDK thing.